# Python using while loop with reading from a file with if statement

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

please can you tell me what is wrong with my code?
I have been trying to make this work it's not happening.

In python, I created a function that I want to search for students by their ID,
I need to make it specific and if it's not int like (str) I want it to show an error message.

I used while true, but it's not working, as it goes to the end of the function without checking the if condition.

Here is the code:

```
    #open the file as student file (variable)
    with open("studentfile.txt","r") as studentfile:
        
        #call upon our reader (this allows us to work with our file)
        studentfileReader=csv.reader(studentfile)
        while True:
         try:
             idnumber=int(input("Please enter student ID :"))
             break
         except ValueError:
             print("Invalid Input")
            
        #for each row that is read by the Reader    
        for row in studentfileReader:
            #and for each field in that row (this does it automatically for us)
            for field in row:
                #if the field is equal to the id number that is being searched for
                if field ==idnumber:
                    #print the row corresponding to that ID number
                    print(row)
                    #Return to main menu for further options or to quit the program
                    
                            
        menu()
```

Maybe there are other ways,
but if I put if statement without while true,
it's not going to show error message for the user inside the program

Comment: The elements of `row` are going to be strings.  None of them could ever be equal to `idnumber`, which is an int.  (And note that you are checking *every* field on each row - presumably you know which column contains the ID, and should only be checking that element.)

Comment: Yes! you are absolutely right! thanks.

Comment: how shall I make it search in that row only?

Comment: usually ID is in first column so you should check only `row[0] == idnumber` without `for`-loop

Comment: if you find row then you could use `return` to exit this function - or even `return row` to get this row outside function and later use it in other functions.